# How to check if variable is empty in phing build xml?

Tags: php, phing

I referred [the documentation](https://www.phing.info/docs/guide/trunk/PhpEvalTask.html) and tried this -

```
<php function="empty" returnProperty="productionSameAsExpectedBranch">
    <param value="${productionDeviationFromExpectedBranch}"/>
</php>
```

But it gives error -

> [php] Calling PHP function: empty()
>   [PHP Error] call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'empty' not found or invalid function name [line 125 of /usr/share/pear/phing/tasks/system/PhpEvalTask.php]

Comment: FWIW, `empty` is a language construct and not a callable function. You'd need to use some equivalent *function* which does a similar thing, like `!strlen`. I don't know anything about Phing though and can't tell you what its way of doing this is.

Comment: can you try with another function instead of `empty` ?

Comment: @deceze Hmm, that makes sense. I think you should add that as a answer. I did something similar - `<php function="strlen" returnProperty="temp">
 <param value="${productionDeviationFromExpectedBranch}"/>
</php>

<if>
 <equals arg1="${temp}" arg2="0" />
 <then>
  <echo>productionSameAsExpectedBranch</echo>
 </then>
 
</if>`

Comment: I'm sure there must be a more idiomatic Phing way of doing that; I'd be very surprised if there wasn't.

Comment: "empty is a language construct" -that doesn't get noticed by many, I guess, because it is called just like any other function. And the documentation, also doesn't mention that..

Comment: @SandeepanNath http://php.net/manual/it/reserved.keywords.php : “ look like functions, some look like constants, and so on - but they're not, really: they are language constructs”

Comment: Only if you don't actually RTFM, including [the notes.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#refsect1-function.empty-notes)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a construct like this:

```
<if>
  <or>
    <not><isset property="productionSameAsExpectedBranch" /></not>
    <and>
      <isset property="productionSameAsExpectedBranch" />
      <equals arg1="${productionSameAsExpectedBranch}" arg2="" />
    </and>
  </or>
  <then>
    <!-- it is not set or empty -->
    <!--property name="productionSameAsExpectedBranch" value="something" override="true" /-->
  </then>
<else />
</if>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `isfalse` condition to check if a string is empty.

```
<target name="empty-string">

    <property name="productionSameAsExpectedBranch" value=""/>

    <if>
        <isfalse value="${productionSameAsExpectedBranch}"/>
        <then>
            <echo>Property is string empty, do something!</echo>
        </then>
    </if>

</target>
```

Note I set `productionSameAsExpectedBranch` to empty string first, I do this to avoid non-existing property. The property will not be overwritten if already exists.

This works because internally `isfalse` uses PHP's casting.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use the [matches](https://www.phing.info/phing/guide/en/output/hlhtml/#conditions.matches) condition with an empty line pattern like:

```xml
<target name="empty-string">

    <property name="productionSameAsExpectedBranch" value=""/>

    <if>
        <matches string="${productionSameAsExpectedBranch}" pattern="^$"/>
        <then>
            <echo>Property is string empty, do something!</echo>
        </then>
    </if>

</target>
```